# Traceback Error in JARVIS voice assistant

Tags: python

I am making Jarvis voice assistant but I am having this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\project\Jarvis\jarvis.py", line 43, in <module>
query = takeCommand().lower()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower
```

and I have also installed pyaudio and it is working

my code is below please have a look

```
import pyttsx3
import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
import Wikipedia

engine = pyttsx3.init("sapi5")
voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
engine.setProperty("voice", voices[0].id)

def speak(audio):
    engine.setProperty("rate", 130)
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour>= 0 and hour<12:
        speak("Good Morning")
    elif hour>= 12 and hour<18:
        speak("Good Afternoon")
    else:
        speak("Good Evening")
    speak("I am Jarvis sir! How may I help you")
def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-in")
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")
    except Exception as e:
         print("Say that again please...")
         return "None"
         return query 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wishMe()
    while True:
        query = takeCommand().lower()
        if 'wikipedia' in query:  
            speak('Searching Wikipedia...')
            query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
            results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2) 
            speak("According to Wikipedia")
            print(results)
            speak(results)
```

I am not able to figure out how to fix this error.
I am doing it using a tutorial on youtube made by CodeWithHarry

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, the takecommand() function doesn't return anything when it recognises audio.  However, you do have a return statement (return query) that looks like it's in the wrong place, if you move it up to before the except line, it should work.  So the function should look like this:

```
def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-in")
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")
        return query
    except Exception as e:
        print("Say that again please...")
        return "None"
```